# Unable to see installed Plugin in Runtime configuration in anypoint studio (Mule based eclipse Ide)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mule, anypoint-studio

I have recently installed plugin for API gateway runtime 2.1.0 in anytime studio but I'm unable to see API gateway runtime plugin in runtime configuration dropdown while creating a new mule project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled anytime studio and install API gateway 2.1.0 plugin now I'm able to see API gateway as Runtime configuration.I hope there could be some better way for the same